# Bootstrap 3 navbar not responding to style changes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's my navbar:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My<b>App</b></a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Learn</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Sign In | Register</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

        <!-- The rest omitted for brevity. -->
```

And my `style.css`:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
    min-height: 200px;
}

.navbar-nav > a {
    color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -4em;
}

.footer, .push {
    height: 4em;
}

.footer {
    background: rgb(0, 100, 255);
}
```

And the corresponding jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/srhwgdsr/

I am trying to do several things here:

- I'm trying to make the header taller, the attempt of which you can see in `style.css` with the `.navbar-fixed-top` rule trying to set the header to a min of 200px; and
- I'm trying to set the color of the links ("Learn", "Contact", "Sign In | Register") red, as you can see in `style.css` with the `.navbar-nav > a` rule; and
- I'm trying to pin the "Sign In | Register" link to the right of the `container-fluid` div), as you can see in the HTML with my use of `pull-right`

Why are none of these attempts working? Do I not have Bootstrap 3 configured correctly? Is something "locked" somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a specificity issue. Bootstrap's CSS is more specific than yours, so it takes precedent. If you use the same selectors that are defined in Bootstrap, it will work correctly. Also, you're using JSFiddle incorrectly. There shouldn't be any meta/head tags and external resources should be defined in the sidebar, not inline.

For instance, to target the links in the header, use this:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

## [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srhwgdsr/1/)

Comment: Thanks @APAD1 (+1) - that helps me with the 2nd issue, any ideas as to the 1st and 3rd? Also, in regards to the 2nd issue (red links), I'm not following what you mean by "specificity issue". I had `.navbar-nav > a`. To me, this says "Apply this rule to any "a" elements that are children of `navbar-nav` elements", which should apply to my links, no? So when you corrected this with `.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a`, I'm still not seeing why my original rule was ignored. Can you elaborate? Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. Basically you weren't being specific enough with your selectors. You were using `.navbar-nav > a` to target links in your menu while Bootstrap was targeting `.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a` which is more specific. In these cases, the selector that is more specific will override the more generic selector, such as the one you had defined. [Read more on specificity here](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). Continued....

Comment: Your first issue is that you are applying the min-height to `.navbar-fixed-top`, but you don't have any elements with that class name in your HTML. For the 3rd issue, instead of using the Bootstrap `pull-right` class(which I don't think will give you the effect you're going for), I would just assign a new class to that `LI` and then position it absolutely. [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srhwgdsr/3/)

Comment: Ahhh, thanks again @APAD1 (+1 again) - can you just confirm this for me: You're saying that somewhere inside `bootstrap.min.css` is a selector that is more specific than the one I provided, and because of that, the browser ignored it? If that's the case, then I fully understand what you're saying. If that's not the case, I'm still confused as to what you mean when you say "**Bootstrap** was targeting"...

Comment: That's exactly what I mean @smeeb. It's actually pretty easy to see this in a developer window. Inspect the element and look at the CSS rules on the right. If you see your CSS rule that you've defined yourself and the rule has a strikethrough, that means it's being overridden by another rule. Then just look at what is overriding your style and use that same selector. Here's a screenshot from your original JSFiddle to show you what I mean: http://s11.postimg.org/hwacfedf7/specificity.jpg

Comment: Ahhh, makes perfect sense then @APAD1 (+1 and thanks yet again). Last followup question: in your latest jsFiddle, I see that the footer is no longer "sticky" like it was in my original jsFiddle that I posted with the question. Did something get removed/overridden somehow? Thanks again!

Comment: Hmmm ya, something must have gotten messed up, try [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/srhwgdsr/4/).

Comment: And one final tip(should have noticed this earlier). `>` is used for specificity, basically what you're saying with that is that you want to target the element that is a direct descendent of the parent element. So your original selector `.navbar-nav > a` wouldn't have worked in the first place, since the `a` is inside of an `li`. So it would have had to have been `.navbar-nav > li > a` to correctly target the header links. If you would have done `.navbar-nav a` that would have targetted any `a` elements within the class `navbar-nav` regardless of hierarchy.